# Has anyone implemented the Autofill Contact on WKWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autofill

I'm trying to implement this on a **WKWebview** on my app. Where in it will open an online form. In this form I need to add the **Autofill Contact** feature. This is available when I access the form on Safari or Google chrome.

Here's the sample screenshot I've access the online form thru Slack

[image]

I've been searching on this for a while but can't seem to find a good source or reference for this. If anyone has a reference on this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is automatically available when you use SFSafariViewController.